# run multiple node instance on same node using pm2

Tags: node.js, puppet, pm2

I want to run  2 node.js application on single server , using pm2 and those application need to deploy via puppet.Could you please advise is this possible.

Regards,
Bala

Answer (score 6):

YOu can run same nodejs app as a cluster via pm2.
https://github.com/Unitech/pm2#commands-overview

```
pm2 start app.js -i 4         # Start 4 instances of application in cluster mode
```

So it balances your processes as well.
it has nothing to do with puppet.

To run multi diff node apps you can check the process.yml

http://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/application-declaration/

and than

```
# Start all applications
$ pm2 start process.json
```

Comment: He wants to create `two` node applications on same server not two instances I think

Comment: hmmm you might be right. anyway via pm2 he can do that too.

Comment: I want to run two different type of nod.js app on single server via pm2 ,is this possible??

Comment: updated my answer, checkout the process.yml/process.json where you define all your apps and start ALL  of them via pm2 start process.json/yml

Comment: @mbm you can run multiple node.js app on a single server each with multiple process. I have pushed it to the limit but it depends on the server's capacity