# Need to host multiple node with PM2 server?

Tags: node.js, server, pm2

How to run **2** or **more** **node app** with **pm2**?
I tried with different ways by referring (https://stackoverflow.com/a/39316957/11983640) and other links also but its not happening.
Any solutions?

Comment: You want to run multiple node projects with pm2 ? or you want to run same project on multiple cores using pm2 ?

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you want to run with pm2 different apps . For that case generate an ecosystem file with :

```
pm2 ecosystem
```

And then set your scripts to run as you want . 
An example :

ecosystem.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  apps : [{
    name: 'MyNodeApp',
    script: 'bin/www',
    args: '',
    instances: 1,
    autorestart: true,
    watch: true,
    max_memory_restart: '1G',
    env: {
      NODE_ENV: 'development'
    },
    env_production: {
      NODE_ENV: 'production'
    }
  },{
    name: 'back-up',
    script: './backup',
    args: '',
    instances: 1,
    autorestart: true,
    watch: true,
    max_memory_restart: '1G',
    env: {
      NODE_ENV: 'development'
    },
    env_production: {
      NODE_ENV: 'production'
    }
  }],
};
```

Run your pm2 with :

```
pm2 start ecosystem.config.js
```

With the above eco file i start 2 different apps with pm2 the first is my main app (name:MyNodeApp) and the second is a back up script .

Comment: Without config.js is it possible? Because I need to write cofig.js in both the app ryt?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to host multiple node projects on pm2, you can just do it like this

```
pm2 start path/to/first/node/project/main_file.js --name "project_1"

pm2 start path/to/another/node/project/main_file.js --name "project_2"
```

Just make sure both projects are running on different port

Comment: Lemme try and vil let you know.